# How to host a Spring Boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, server, hosting, web-deployment

I developed a spring boot application (REST API) with an H2 database. Now there are many questions that I have about the deploying of this application.

1. How can I upload this project to my web host?
2. Do every web hosting supports this kind of application?
3. Will I have a problem with this H2 database and I will have to migrate to (for example) MySql?

Comment: You could try https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-spring-boot-apps-to-heroku

Answer (score 0):

1. If your web host is supporting Java you can run the application
2. No. Usually there is only PHP support
3. You can use H2 (I assume you are using it file base) or MySQL if your hoster supports MySQL